# VirtualBox crashes after starting gdb in Visual Studio Code

Tags: json, gdb, virtualbox, visual-studio-code

I'm a new apprentice at my company, so I'm new to Stackoverflow and coding in general, please bear with me.

I wanted to get away from the text editors (gedit and geany) I used before and started looking for an IDE. I chose to use Visual Studio Code, and started setting it up. I had to set up a compiler and a debugger. The compiler worked, but the debugger is making trouble.

I am running Debian 64 bit in a virtual machine, the host system is windows 10 64 bit. This is my launch.json file:

```
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "C++ Launch",
            "type": "cppdbg",
            "request": "launch",
            "program": "/usr/bin/gdb",
            "args": [],
            "stopAtEntry": false,
            "cwd": "${workspaceRoot}",
            "environment": [],
            "externalConsole": true,
            "linux": {
                "MIMode": "gdb"
            },
            "osx": {
                "MIMode": "lldb"
            },
            "windows": {
                "MIMode": "gdb"
            }
        },
        {
            "name": "C++ Attach",
            "type": "cppdbg",
            "request": "attach",
            "program": "/usr/bin/gdb",
            "processId": "${command.pickProcess}",
            "linux": {
                "MIMode": "gdb"
            },
            "osx": {
                "MIMode": "lldb"
            },
            "windows": {
                "MIMode": "gdb"
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

As you can see, I set the program to gdb. Now if i try to debug my code with "C++ Launch" the terminal window for the gdb debugger will open, and the VSCode window looks like it is in debug mode.
[Shortly before my Virtual machine crashes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hWwxd.png)

Then my Virtual Machine just crashes, without any error message. My virtual machine client says [canceled](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k8B4n.png). I looked into every logfile that seemed at least a little relevant. I checked the virtual machine log. I google this problem in various ways. I checked if it crashes even if I close gdb before the crash (it does). And still I haven't found a way to prevent this crash from happening.

I asked most of my co-workers and they don't know an answer either.

This is my first post/question, if I made any mistakes (format, formulation, etc.) please tell me, so the next time I want to ask something it will be better.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Tags should include json? (and maybe not C?)

Comment: Fixed the tags, sorry

Comment: Here is a _[post](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/7509)_ that list a similar (not identical) problem.

Comment: Thanks for linking, sadly the fixes in the post didn't work for me.